# Adding resources to solution explorer in experimental hive

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dsl-tools, visual-studio-sdk

I'm currently working on a project using DSL tools in Visual Studio 2008.

Is there a way to automatically add a resource into the solution explorer of the experimental hive at runtime? I'm creating new diagrams based on what is on screen, and saving them into the directory the project is stored in. I would like to know if there is a way to get them to automatically get added to the solution explorer? (I don't want to have to drag the files in manually each time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to modify the project file. However, visual studio would then reload the project.

Comment: That works, however it has the undesired effect of reloading the project... Good tip though, thanks! :)